# Error while importing "from visual import *"

Tags: python, pip

I have installed `python-visual` using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-visual
sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev
```

It is showing this error when I am trying to `import visual`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
from visual.ui import display
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/ui.py", line 3, in <module>
import materials
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/materials.py", line 152, in <module>
tx_turb3 = raw_texture( data=reshape(data,(64,64,64,3)), interpolate=True, mipmap=False )
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visual/materials.py", line 70, in __init__
self.__setattr__(key, value)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: In which moment does it show this error? During installation?

Comment: when i am trying to import visual

Comment: Might not be the best, but this solved my similar problem using the comment code part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392418/using-vpython-in-pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing a newer version of `python-visual` and `libgtkglextmm`.